# Safari on IOS generates "ReferenceError: Ca ni n't find variable:"

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

The following code is working correctly for all browsers including Safari on Mac, with the exception of Safari on the iPhone.

I have a timer Object that could potentially be running that is defined like so:

```
//delay background change until animation is finished
lastTimer = setTimeout(function () {
  $('#' + targetDiv).removeClass('open');
}, 150);
```

Later, I need to check if the timer is running, and if so cancel it. Here is the code I am using:

```
if (lastTimer != null) { clearTimeout(lastTimer); }
```

This is where IOS Safari generates the JavaScript Error:

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: lastTimer".

Any ideas on why the check for null is not preventing the error, like it seems to with the other browsers?

Here is the full code for the two pertaining functions in answer to the reply below: (edited with solution)

```
// Class for handling the animations for the drop down menus
var dropDownMenu = {
lastTimer: null,
openMenu: function (targetDiv) {
    if (targetDiv != null) {
        var targetHeight = $('#' + targetDiv).height();
        $('#' + targetDiv).stop(true); //stop an previous animations and clear queue
        if (this.lastTimer != null) { clearTimeout(this.lastTimer); } //stop possible pending timer to prevent background change
        console.log("testing b");
        $('#mainNavigation #dropDownMenu ul').removeClass('open'); // make sure all closed menus show corrent bgd
        $('#' + targetDiv).animate({
            bottom: -(targetHeight + 30)
        }, 200, 'swing');
        $('#' + targetDiv).addClass('open');
    }

},
closeMenu: function (targetDiv) {
    if (targetDiv != null) {
        $('#' + targetDiv).stop(true); //stop an previous animations and clear queue
        $('#' + targetDiv).animate({
            bottom: 0
        }, 200, 'swing');
        //delay background change until animation is finished
        this.lastTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#' + targetDiv).removeClass('open');
        }, 150);
    }
}
}
```

When the error happens in iOS the execution stops and my test `console.log` immediately after does not execute.

Comment: Is it a global variable? Is there any code that is conditionally run based on the browser? Can you provide more code?

Comment: added full code for the two functions above. They are in a class together, but the timer itself is not global. It worked in all other browsers correctly, so I was hoping to avoid making it a global var.

Comment: If it isn't global, where is it declared? I don't see a `var lastTimer` anywhere. If you haven't declared the variable, then try putting `var lastTimer;` just before the `var dropDownMenu = {` line.

Comment: _"I was hoping to avoid making it a global var"_ Not setting `var` means global.

Comment: Okay, I just tried defining it as variable in the class, and edited the code above to include the change. The result was the same however. I would prefer to keep any variables related to the menu within the object definition.

Comment: @Mark1270287: That's not what I said to do. You've made it a property of the object. Please try what I suggested before trying something else. JavaScript does not have classes. If you do want it as a property, then you'd need to change to `this.lastTimer`.

Comment: Okay, defining it as a property and adding the this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark1270287: You're welcome. For some reason your `openMenu` must be getting called first when in IOS/Safari. Assigning to an undeclared variable works, but trying to read the undeclared variable does not. The solution is to be certain to declare vars first. But having it as a property instead of a variable is good too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I want to chime in on this to explain. Mobile Safari is less forgiving when checking for undefined using the simple check,

```
if variable
```

When you come across situations like this then use,

```
if typeof variable === "undefined"
```

Attaching the variable to "this" is one solution here but it's just taking advantage of the fact that definedVariable.undefinedProperty returns undefined, whereas referencing an undefined variable directly will cause the reference error in some runtime environments.

I would advise not getting into the habit of attaching to "this" if it's not necessary.

Comment: That makes sense. That would explain why the issue was only happening in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Just curious, why should attaching to "this" be avoided? It seems like making it a property on the object would be a good practice to avoid naming conflicts with other scripts, as well as allow multiple instances to each have their own timer reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that on IOS, the `openMenu` is being invoked first.

This means that you're trying to get the value of an undeclared variable, resulting in the `ReferenceError`.

Oddly, you can *assign* to an undeclared variable, which implicitly makes it global. So if `closeMenu` is called first, then the assignment happens first, making the variable implicitly declared.

The proper solution is to always declare variables before using them.

```
var lastTimer;
```

But as it turned out, you preferred to use a property on the current object instead of a variable. As such, the solution was to access the property in the methods...

```
this.lastTimer
```

This will never throw a `ReferenceError`, even if the property is not declared.

Comment: Actually, the openMenu is being called first in all browsers. It had to be, because the closeMenu could not get called until the menu was open. What is odd is that is that except ios Safari, all other browsers ignored the fact that it wasn't defined.

I preferred the property solution because it minimized conflicts with other scripts.

Comment: @Mark1270287: Well something else was going on then to declare `lastTimer` before `openMenu` was called, because browsers can't ignore it. Asking for the value of an undeclared variable is a *ReferenceError* by specification. Anyway, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

There's one other potential issue that I think needs to be stated.  Safari on iOS* can be very aggressive on caching and not reloading a clean copy of your code.

e.g. if you executed one version of your code without the variable defined, then fixed the code but the error continues to show on reloading (even if you close the browser/reboot the phone)

To solve this, tap and hold (aka Long Press) the reload icon in the address bar and a menu pops up with 2 options **Request Desktop Site** and **Reload Without Content Blockers**.  Choosing either one of these causes a ***Real*** reload of all of the content... which resolves the issue with any cached buggy code.

*Not just Safari.  Chrome on iOS (which is built on Apple's version of WebKit) can exhibit the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global variable in your code. Not declaring var makes it global.

Try changing:

```
if (lastTimer != null)
```

to

```
if (typeof lastTimer !=="undefined" && lastTimer)
```

if you are sticking with it being global.

Comment: Yuck. This buries the issue instead of dealing with it.

Comment: This probably would have worked as well. I have fixed it another way based on am not i am's comment.  am not i am, please add your soluitona as an aswer and I would will mark this answered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case Safari 13 didnt work with ES6 `const` hence i needed to replace it with `var`